# Can an SDE be turned into PDE for the density?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $W_t$ be a Wiener Process. Then the brownian motion $B_t$ solves the SDE $$dB_t = dW_t$$ while the density $f(x,t)$ of $B_t$ with $B_0 = 0$ solves the diffusion equation
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}.$$

Let $dX_t = a(X_t,t)dt + b(X_t,t)dW_t$ be another SDE.
Are there positive results about the possibility of deriving a PDE from $a$ and $b$ which will be solved by the density of the solutions of the SDE (if existant)? At least if $a(X_t,t) = a(X_t)$ and/or $b(X_t,t) = b(X_t)$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fokker%E2%80%93Planck_equation

Comment: If this was an answer i would accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed as mentioned in the comments, this is the [backward equation](https://cims.nyu.edu/%7Eholmes/teaching/asa19/handout_Lecture10_2019.pdf).

In ["Existence and uniqueness of martingale solutions for SDEs with rough or degenerate coefficients"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022123607003709), the study this equation even for time-dependent coefficients $b(t,x),\sigma(t,x)$ with low regularity.

See here for more references ["Each diffusion SDE is associated to a *unique* family of transition kernels"](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/451967/each-diffusion-sde-is-associated-to-a-unique-family-of-transition-kernels/451970#451970).